# extract unique characters in an excel range except some characters function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

If an excel has string data in A1:B100, I want to extract characters except A-Z a-z 0-1 and display one time per character. I want to get like +,-, etc.
Could someone please give me a hand?

Example Data is

```
+------------+------+
|    ColA    | ColB |
+------------+------+
| Blue Berry | 4    |
| Apple      | 4+   |
| Orange;    | 44   |
+------------+------+
```

I want the result in one cell as Space+;

Comment: go for regex in vba

Comment: Plese edit the question and add the description what is input data (not the entire range, just few cells) and what is expected output for that input, add e. g. screenshots.

Comment: agreed with Omega. Am thinking in the direction of a custom user defined function though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub showspecials()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, msg As String
    Dim S As String, L As String, CH As String
    Set rng = Range("A1:B100")
    msg = ""

    For Each r In rng
        S = r.Text
        L = Len(S)
        If L <> 0 Then
            For i = 1 To L
                If Mid(S, i, 1) Like "[0-9a-zA-Z]" Then
                Else
                    msg = msg & vbCrLf & Mid(S, i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r

        MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want a character to appear **only one time** in the `MsgBox`, then use:

```
Sub showspecials()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, msg As String
    Dim S As String, L As String, CH As String
    Dim i As Long, pat As String

    Set rng = Range("A1:B100")
    msg = ""
    pat = "[0-9a-zA-Z]"

    For Each r In rng
        S = r.Text
        L = Len(S)
        If L <> 0 Then
            For i = 1 To L
                CH = Mid(S, i, 1)
                If CH Like pat Then
                Else
                    If InStr(msg, CH) = 0 Then
                        msg = msg & vbCrLf & CH
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r

        MsgBox msg
End Sub
```